# Как сохранить состояние QTableWidget в PyQt5 QSettings?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qsettings

Вот простенькая программа и как бы я не старался у меня не получается сохранить изменения введённые пользователем, помогите плииз!

**main.py**:

```
#import subprocess
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QCoreApplication, QSettings, QVariant
from table import Ui_MainWindow      


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, rows):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.rows = rows
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set_row_count)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.set_row_count2)

    def set_row_count(self):
        self.rows += 1        
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.rows)

    def set_row_count2(self):
        self.rows -= 1        
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.rows)

number_rows = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow(number_rows)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**table.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(531, 301)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 511, 211))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 51, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 230, 51, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 531, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
```

Comment: Если ты имеешь ввиду, что значения которые вводишь в ячейку таблицы не сохраняется между запусками, то можешь попробовать сохранять таблицу в csv формат например, либо написать какую-нибудь функцию для сохранения данных в файл при изменении состояния этой ячейки например с помощью cellChanged.

Comment: @james  то что вы предлагаете, имеет смысл только в том случае, если мы говорим о безликих цифрах и буквах. Представьте себе, что в таблице данные разных шрифтов и имеют разные цвета. В файл вы такое не сохраните !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать так:

```
import contextlib
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(531, 301)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 511, 211))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 51, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 230, 51, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 531, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))


class SettingsManager:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.m_settings = QtCore.QSettings(filename, QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)

    @property
    def settings(self):
        return self.m_settings

    def read(self, widget):
        self.settings.beginGroup(widget.objectName())
        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
            selectionMode = self.settings.value(
                "selectionMode", type=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode
            )
            widget.setSelectionMode(selectionMode)

        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
            rowCount = self.settings.value("rowCount", type=int)
            columnCount = self.settings.value("columnCount", type=int)
            widget.setRowCount(rowCount)
            widget.setColumnCount(columnCount)
            items = self.settings.value("items")
            if items is None:
                self.read_defaults(widget)
            else:
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
                while not stream.atEnd():
                    it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                    i = stream.readInt()
                    j = stream.readInt()
                    stream >> it
                    widget.setItem(i, j, it)
                selecteditems = self.settings.value("selecteditems")
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(
                    selecteditems, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly
                )
                while not stream.atEnd():
                    i = stream.readInt()
                    j = stream.readInt()
                    it = widget.item(i, j)
                    if it is not None:
                        it.setSelected(True)
        self.settings.endGroup()

    def write(self, widget):
        self.settings.beginGroup(widget.objectName())
        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
            self.settings.setValue("selectionMode", widget.selectionMode())

        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
            self.settings.setValue("rowCount", widget.rowCount())
            self.settings.setValue("columnCount", widget.columnCount())
            items = QtCore.QByteArray()
            stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
            for i in range(widget.rowCount()):
                for j in range(widget.columnCount()):
                    it = widget.item(i, j)
                    if it is not None:
                        stream.writeInt(i)
                        stream.writeInt(j)
                        stream << it
            self.settings.setValue("items", items)
            selecteditems = QtCore.QByteArray()
            stream = QtCore.QDataStream(
                selecteditems, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly
            )
            for it in widget.selectedItems():
                # print(it.row(), it.column())
                stream.writeInt(it.row())
                stream.writeInt(it.column())
            self.settings.setValue("selecteditems", selecteditems)
        self.settings.endGroup()

    def release(self):
        self.m_settings.sync()

    def read_defaults(self, widget):
        if  widget.objectName() == "tableWidget":
            widget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
            widget.setRowCount(1)
            widget.setColumnCount(5)
            for i in range(widget.rowCount()):
                for j in range(widget.columnCount()):
                    it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("{}-{}".format(i, j))
                    widget.setItem(i, j, it)


@contextlib.contextmanager
def settingsContext(filename):
    manager = SettingsManager(filename)
    try:
        yield manager
    finally:
        manager.release()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): #(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set_row_count)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.set_row_count2)        

        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 1)

        self.read_settings()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def set_row_count(self):
#        self.rows += 1        
#        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.rows)
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def set_row_count2(self):
#        self.rows -= 1        
#        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.rows)
        if self.tableWidget.rowCount() > 0:
            self.tableWidget.removeRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount()-1)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.write_settings()
        super().closeEvent(event)

    def read_settings(self):
        with settingsContext("data_T_W.ini") as m:
            for children in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget):
                if children.objectName():
                    m.read(children)

    def write_settings(self):
        with settingsContext("data_T_W.ini") as m:
            for children in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget):
                if children.objectName():
                    m.write(children)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(540, 380)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!)

Comment: @НикитаТимофеев пожалуйста.

Comment: Я так долго мучался с этим вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: @НикитаТимофеев для таблиц это не очень просто.

Comment: Но так уж получилось что мне надо было именно для них.

Comment: А можно спросить, как применить это к другим программам?