# База данных для приложения созданного на питоне

Tags: python, pyqt5

Всем привет! Я пишу свое небольшое приложение на питоне по сбору данных, и хочу сделать базу данных
для сохранение настроек, которые ведёт пользователь чтобы при каждом запуске опять не настраивать 
настройки. Я совсем новичок в базах данных хочется научится посоветуйте пожалуйста какую учить (думаю
правильно выразился). Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @AlexF, тогда можно использовать qt-шное решение -- [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#details), он может в реестре сохранять или в `ini`

Comment: может чем поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074339/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-tablewidget-%d0%b2-pyqt5-qsettings/1074398#1074398

Comment: или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084786/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-checkbox-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be/1084822#1084822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я обычно пользуюсь словарями

```
config = {"name": "Tolya", "date": "6687"}
```

И так далее. Это для примера данные :)

Их можно сохранять в файл с помощью библиотеки json

```
import json

res = {"key1": 6}

f = open("config.data","w")
json.dump(res, f, indent=4)
f.close()
```

Чтение с файла:

```
import json

f = open("config.data","r")
res = json.load(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: а как вы обычно сохраняете шрифты, цвета и ..., если они присутствуют и важны?

Comment: Есть меню в приложение, там есть 3 действия, пользователь может выбрать только одно действие, если он выберет другое то старое сбросится. И если он выбрал действие то при выходе приложение и запуске это действие сохранялось