# Сохранить сортировки и ширины колонок таблиц в форме Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qsettings

Есть форма, в которой находится 10 таблиц `QTabelView`. 
При работе с формой пользователь сам выбирает ширину колонок и сортировку.

Каждый раз при выходи из формы я собираю название таблиц и в цикле сохраняю выбранные настройки в `config` файл и соответственно каждый раз их загружаю при в входе в форму.

Хотелось бы узнать если *PyQt* возможность делать это более просто. 
Некая настройка, которая сохраняет всю структуру формы глобально для экрана.

Comment: Не чего лучшее чем это не нашел. (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074339/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-tablewidget-%d0%b2-pyqt5-qsettings?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См. комментарии

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QTableWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QVariant


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    # функция сохранения. В качестве параметра передается объект QTableWidget
    def saveTable(self, table):
        settings = QSettings("config.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.beginGroup("main")
        header = table.horizontalHeader().saveState()
        settings.setValue(f'{table.objectName()}_header', header)
        settings.endGroup()
        settings.sync()

    # функция восстановления заголовка. В качестве параметра передается объект QTableWidget
    def restoreTable(self,table):
        settings = QSettings("config.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.beginGroup("main")
        value = QVariant(settings.value(f'{table.objectName()}_header', None))
        if value.value():
            table.horizontalHeader().restoreState(value.value())

    # сохранение заголовков всех объектов
    # ВАЖНО. детишки типа QTableWidget будут искаться непосредственно на главном окне. 
    # Если таблицы в контейнерах (табы, фреймы), то искать надо именно в них
    # Или делать рекурсивную функцию обхода всего дерева объектов  
    def saveClicked(self):
        for child in self.findChildren(QTableWidget):
            self.saveTable(child)

    # То же что сохранение
    def loadClicked(self):
        # Ищем все таблицы, расположенные на self и восстанавливаем их заголовок
        for child in self.findChildren(QTableWidget):
            self.restoreTable(child)
        self.repaint()

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.grid_layout)
        for i in range(1,6):
            self.table = QTableWidget(self)
            self.table.setColumnCount(4)
            self.table.setRowCount(2)
            self.table.setRowCount(100)
            self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["one", "two", "three", "four"])
            self.table.setObjectName(f"table{i}")
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.table, i, 0,1,2)
        self.savebutton = QPushButton("save")
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.savebutton, 6, 0)
        self.savebutton.clicked.connect(self.saveClicked)
        self.loadbutton = QPushButton("load")
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.loadbutton, 6, 1)
        self.loadbutton.clicked.connect(self.loadClicked)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Добрался до это сам. Но не без Вашей помощи. Еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Это очень просто. Сохраним и размеры колонок и сортировки буквально в пару строк.
Помимо размеров сохранятся и растяжения (если есть столбцы Stretch) и если используется - какие столбцы скрыты для отображения.

**save** - сохранит состояние горизонтального заголовка для self.table, а **restore** соответственно загрузит из инишки и применит

```
def save(self):
    settings = QSettings("config.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
    settings.beginGroup("main")
    header = self.table.horizontalHeader().saveState()
    settings.setValue("header", header)
    settings.endGroup()
    settings.sync()
def restore(self):
    settings = QSettings("config.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
    settings.beginGroup("main")
    value = QVariant(settings.value("header", None))
    if value:
        state = value.value()
        self.table.horizontalHeader().restoreState(state)
```

Comment: То есть необходимо перебирать каждый tableview по отдельности? В моем приложение очень много таблиц хотелось бы избежать избыточности

Comment: Если заранее известно что за таблицы, в цикле перебрать не проблема.. Если нет, то также не проблема. добавлю еще одним ответом

Comment: Низкий поклон. Спасибо за помощь